# SQL Server Authentication via Group Membership

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I have an issue which I just can't understand with a couple of SQL instances which I inherited from previous DBA.

Environment details

- SQL Server 2012 with SP3
- Windows Server 2012
- Users, groups and Servers on same domain
- NT Group setup as a Global Group (Security group, not a distribution group)
- Users are added to AD group Domain\Group1
- Domain\Group1 is setup as a login in SQL with login permissions and
  access to databases

Based on the above, I'd expect all users who are members of Domain\Group1 to be able to login to SQL servers. However when users try to login they receive an error message

> login failed for user domain\xxxx (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 18456)

Steps carried out to check the issue so far:
Checked the error logs on SQL server and I can see the following two messages

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
>   Login failed for user 'domain\xxxx'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided

Checked Ring Buffer by running the query below

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar(30), GETDATE(), 121) as runtime,
dateadd (ms, (a.[Record Time] - sys.ms_ticks), GETDATE()) as [Notification_Time],
a.* , sys.ms_ticks AS [Current Time]
FROM
(SELECT
x.value('(//Record/Error/ErrorCode)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS [ErrorCode],
x.value('(//Record/Error/CallingAPIName)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS [CallingAPIName],
x.value('(//Record/Error/APIName)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS [APIName],
x.value('(//Record/Error/SPID)[1]', 'int') AS [SPID],
x.value('(//Record/@id)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Record Id],
x.value('(//Record/@type)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS [Type],
x.value('(//Record/@time)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Record Time]
FROM (SELECT CAST (record as xml) FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
WHERE ring_buffer_type = 'RING_BUFFER_SECURITY_ERROR') AS R(x)) a
CROSS JOIN sys.dm_os_sys_info sys
ORDER BY a.[Record Time] ASC
```

This returns a lot of

> 0x534  LookupAccountSidInternal    LookupAccountSid    63  178 RING_BUFFER_SECURITY_ERROR

Checked SPNs and it seems to all be registered ok, running the following code returns KERBEROS

```
SELECT auth_scheme FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@spid ;
```

Checked the following two lines of code generate expected results; the first one lists all members of the group and the second one shows a path from the user to sql via the group

```
Exec xp_logininfo 'Domain\Group1', 'members'
Exec xp_logininfo 'Domain\xxxx', 'all'
```

Adding the users individually works and they can access the server

I am totally stuck!

Comment: check this link :https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456

Comment: Thank you @TheGameiswar. I have come across this blog but I am afraid it was no help. The blog suggests that state 5 error occurs if the login attempt comes from the local machine; which isn't the case.

Also trying to specify the database name in the connection in SSMS still gave the same login failed message

Comment: Is the group a security group or a distribution group? You can check this in the AD Users and Computers tool or with powershell (`get-adgroup group1 | select -expandproperty groupcategory`). If it isn't as security group, you can't use it to authenticate to SQL.

Comment: Hi @BenThul, sorry should have specified this in the question - It is set as as security group and works against some other instances we have (exactly same setup as above)

Comment: Weird (and frustrating)! Are the service accounts between an instance that works and one that doesn't the same? How about the results of the `xp_logininfo` queries? `sys.login_token` (as applied to one of the affected logins)?

Comment: Could you try the following please and let us know the outcome:
- if possible get the user to try and connect directly from ssns running on the same machine as the server
- try changing the group from global to universal and retry login